# How to find simple ip address of local server

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ip

This may be something ***very*** simple and obvious but I’m learning the command line. I’m trying to identify the IP address I need to load in a web browser to access my local server - for example, after entering these simple steps in the command line to create a folder with an index file:

```
mkdir www
nano index.html
```

Then running the server:

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

Displays this message: `[1] 41749`

What IP address do I need to load in a web browser to see the test index.html file? I’ve tried:

http://127.0.0.1/
http://localhost/

Also, entering `hostname -i` returns this message:

```
hostname: illegal option -- i
usage: hostname [-fs] [name-of-host]
```

Can anyone explain what’s going on here? Probably something very obvious. Also it feels that other commands aren’t working as usual as the `ip addr` command now returns `-bash: ip: command not found`.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Very short principle description that should put you on track: Connect to the server and use "host localhost" command to find out server's ip address. Than you have to figure out the home directory for SimpleHTTPServer and put your website index.html file ther to test it. At the end use http://#IP_ADDR#/index.html and you should see the page.

Comment: What OS are you running? Anyway, maybe your web server is running on the IP of a specific network interface. Try the ifconfig (since ip is not installed) command, to figure out what IP addresses are currently used on your system